# Manipulating __artifactId__ during file generation by maven archetype

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-archetype

Building a Maven archetype where files are generated using **_*artifactId*_**. archetype.xml looks like:

```
<sources>
    <source>src/main/java/__artifactId__.java</source>
    <source>src/main/java/__artifactId__CommandExecutor.java</source>
    <source>src/main/java/__artifactId__EventListener.java</source>
</sources>
```

Generating a project using this archetype can lead to Java file names that do not follow the naming convention such as sample-plugin.java and sample-pluginCommandExecutor.java.

How can I make sure **_*artifactId*_** is converted to appropriate Java file name, such as  SamplePlugin.java and SamplePluginCommandExecutor.java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an archetype expert, in fact I just did it once but
faced with a very similar problem.

I was not able to find a way to customize file or directory names
in any way, I mean use one of the archetype parameters and transform
it.

So there are 2 kinds of solution I used

- Add a new archetype parameter where you specify the class name
- Use a standard Name (like ArtifactClass.java) and then create an maven profile (enabled if this file is present) with an ant script that changes the name (just remember inside your files you can use velocity to customize it)

Hope it helps
tonio

Comment: I was thinking about using a fixed class name route but would like to explore the option of passing the parameter approach.

However the parameter is accessible as ${property}. The current source file is named as ____artifactId____.java. How would the new source file be named in this case ?

Comment: Lets say your parameter is mainClassName, so in your archetype the class should be called ____mainClassName____.java (2 underscores on both sides), I used this approach for directory names, I guess it will work for filenames too.